# Is python socket able to be used all over the world?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm coding a python multiuser chat app. But python doesn't let me connect with computers outside my personal WI-FI zone.
I've tried

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
local_hostname = socket.gethostname()
local_fqdn = socket.getfqdn()
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(local_hostname)
```

I've also tried using my ipv4, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: you may try to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for forwaring/tunneling it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, yes.

In practice, most computers are behind a NAT and/or a firewall, either of which will prevent connection.

- NAT - This is used to work around limitations in the IPv4 address space size. To avoid it, the destination needs to have a publicly routable address.
- Firewall - This is used to filter out attacks. To work with this, the destination firewall needs to be configured to expect your connection.

Comment: Note that publicly routable IPv4 addresses are hard to obtain.  Your NAT will generally assign your computer an address that is private to your network.